# how to start an app within container automatically using docker-compose.yml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I often have to recreate my container using "docker-compose up" command. The problem I have is every time after I recreate the container, I have to go to terminal within the container to run command like "sudo service xx start" to start the app. Is there provision for me to include that sudo command within my docker-compose file? so that I can avoid this extra step.

I tried adding following line within docker-compose but does not work "command: sudo service.."

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Does it throw an error when you add the command, or it just ignores it? Can you post your docker-compose file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Docker needs a process to keep running otherwise the container will exit. Therefore a `sudo service xx start` which starts the process in background won't work. 
One possible solution is to append another command such as `tail` or `bash`:

```
command: service xx start && tail -f /dev/null
```

**Edited** to add a concrete example with `cron`.

The `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get -y install cron

# Create the log file to run run tail
RUN touch /var/log/cron.log

# set the CMD and ENTRYPOINT in docker-compose
```

Build the image

```
docker build -t my-test .
```

Add `entrypoint` and `command` in `docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.4"
services:
 service:
   image: my-test
   entrypoint: /bin/bash
   command: -c "service cron start && tail -f /var/log/cron.log"
```

By adding the `tail` command the container does not exit.

Comment: probably this is the correct way to do as many seem to suggest similar answer. But unfortunately it doesnt work for me. Probably because I am having "entrypoint: /bin/bash" or there is syntax error

Comment: @Pal I edited the answer to add an example with `/bin/bash` as `entrypoint`. Hope it helps

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thank you so much. @b0gusb